# Is the extension by the zeros of the polynomial $f((x)=x^{2m}-p^{2n}=0$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ totally ramified?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^{2m}-p^{2n}=0$ over the $p$-adic field $\mathbb Q_p$. Note that $m,n$ are positive integers and $\gcd(m,n)=1$. I want to study the field extension by the zeros of $f(x)$.

We can rewrite $f(x)=(x^m-p^n)(x^m+p^n)=f_1(x) f_2(x)$, where $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are Eisenstein polynomials and of course irreducible since $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Clearly, zeros of $f_1(x)$ give a degree $m$ extension of $\mathbb Q_p$, which is totally ramified, and the same is true for the zeros of $f_2(x)$.

But the compositum of totally ramified extensions may not be compositum.

> What is the degree of extension? When is it totally ramified?

In both cases of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, the unifomizer is $p$. Thus, I think the compositum will be totally ramified. I found some discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15666/when-is-the-composition-of-two-totally-ramified-extension-totally-ramified#:%7E:text=Thus%2C%20the%20compositum%20of%20two,and%206%20of%20arXiv:0909.2541.)

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$? The compositum of two totally ramified extensions is not always totally ramified. Thus,it's a bit unclear for me why the logic following 'Thus,' in the last paragraph unless you justify your argument.

Comment: @Pont, $m,n$ are positive integers and coprime to each other. Regarding the total ramification, Yes, I agree with you that the compositum of totally ramified extension may not be totally ramified. Maybe some condition is required or some other argument is there.

Comment: The edit has not really addressed the comment. (The claim that the composite extension has degree $m$ remains unjustified.)

Comment: All the roots of the polynomial differ (multiplicatively) by roots of unity, no? Doesn't this make this an easy exercise in cyclotomic extensions?

Comment: How are $f_1,f_2$ Eisenstein polynomials? Isn’t the constant coefficient supposed to have valuation one?

Comment: Amending @Aphelli's comment, maybe one should start with the case $n=1$. Can you (MAS) tackle that one at least?

Comment: @Aphelli, sorry I missed. Yes $f_1, f_2$ are not Eisensetin always, however, if $n=1$, then they are Eisenstein, may be i had this in mind

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, for $n=1$ both are $f_1, f_2$ are Eisenstein. $f_1$ gives the totally ramified extension $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[m]{p}$ while $f_2$ gives the totally ramified extension $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[m]{-p}$. Now if $m=p-1$, then $\mathbb Q_p(\sqrt[m]{-p})=\mathbb Q_p(\zeta_p)$=cyclotomic extension. I don't know more than that. What cyclotomic extensions are you connecting? Can you please clarify?

Comment: What I mean is that if $\alpha$ is any root of $x^m-p^n$, then all the other roots of this are $\zeta^i \alpha$ ($i=1,..., m-1$) where $\zeta$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity; and the roots of $x^m+p^n$ are the $\xi \cdot \zeta^i \alpha$, where $\xi$ is a primitive ($2^{\nu_2(m)+1}$)-th root of unity. In particular, for odd $m$, the two polynomials have the same splitting field (their respective roots are just the negatives of each other's).

Comment: By the way in your question it is not clear if you want to adjoin one individual, or all of the roots of the polynomial(s). If you adjoin all of them i.e. look at splitting fields, as per above, that contains cyclotomic fields which in general are not ramified, even in the case $n=1$. (The polynomial being Eisenstein implies that the extension from adjoining one single root is totally ramified; the splitting field is, in general, not).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I am adjoining all roots of $f(x)$

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, why is $\xi$ a primitive $2^{\nu_2(m)+1}$-th root of unity?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, for odd $m$, $f(x)=x^{2m}-p^{2m}$ has degree extension $m$ as both $f_1, f_2$ have same splitting field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's work in a fixed algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$. You say (in a comment) you want to adjoin *all* roots of $f(x)$, i.e. you are looking at the splitting field of that polynomial. Let $\alpha$ be any one such root.

Then it's basic theory of cyclic field extensions (this is the "easy direction" of Kummer theory) that this splitting field can be seen as the compositum of, on the one hand, $\mathbb Q_p(\alpha)$, and on the other hand, $K_{2m} := \mathbb Q_p(\mu_{2m})$, the cyclotomic extension by the $2m$-th roots of unity.

Now for sure, the first field $\mathbb Q_p(\alpha)$ *is* totally ramified: As discussed in comments, the polynomial $f$ and/or its factors $f_1, f_2$ are technically only Eisenstein for $n=1$, but the proof idea for this generalizes immediately. Alternatively one could see this with the Newton polygon (which has only one slope), or even more basic by noticing that i) the extension has degree $\le m$ and ii) because $m,n$ are coprime, there exist $k, \ell$ such that $v_p(\frac{\alpha^k}{p^\ell}) = \frac{1}{m}$ i.e. the value group of $\mathbb Q_p$ has index at least $m$ in the value group of $\mathbb Q_p(\alpha)$.

But that second field, the cyclotomic $K_{2m}$, is *in general not* totally ramified: By well-known facts about roots of unity in $p$-adics, this field contains a proper unramified extension *unless* $2m$ is of the form $p^r \cdot d$, with $d$ a divisor of $p-1$, and $r \in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. (Here and from now on, I assume $p$ is odd, and leave the case $p=2$ to you.)

So $2m$ being "a power of $p$, times a divisor of $p-1$" is a **necessary criterion** for our composite splitting field to be totally ramified.

Now in case $2m | (p-1)$ (i.e. $r=0$ i.e. $K_{2m} = \mathbb Q_p$), of course the compositum is just the totally ramified $\mathbb Q_p(\alpha)$, so it is totally ramified. That is, $2m$ being a divisor of $p-1$ happens to be **sufficient** for what you want.

But in the remaining cases $2m = p^r \cdot d$, $r \ge 1$, I do not see right away whether the compositum of our two fields (albeit each of them is totally ramified) is also totally ramified. That needs a closer look, and unlike anything so far, might even depend on whether $\alpha$ is a root of $f_1$ or $f_2$. (I described in comments the slight distinction between roots of the one and the other. Note also that e.g. in the case $m=p-1$ you brought up, the splitting fields of each of the factors $f_1, f_2$, respectively, are totally ramified by slightly altered arguments -- now $m | (p-1)$ is enough --, but their compositum, i.e. the splitting field of $f$, is not, as per above.)

Comment: I think that for $m=p$ (odd), one can still argue "by hand" the compositum is totally ramified, as the value group (norming $v(p)=1$) must now contain both $1/(p-1)$ (from the cyclotomic extension) and $1/p$, hence also $1/(p(p-1))$ which is the degree of the extension. There's just no space for ramification to disappear. But I'm not sure what happens as soon as $m$ is a prime power of exponent $\ge 2$, i.e. the ramification of the cyclotomic field is wild as well.